# ASP.NET Unit test basic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

Could someone please help me? This is my unit test:

```
namespace UnitTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class HomeController
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Index_NoInputs_ReturnsDefaultViewResult()
        {
            // Arrange
            HomeController controller = new HomeController();

            // Act
            ViewResult result = Index() as ViewResult;

            // Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
            Assert.AreEqual("", result.ViewName);
            Assert.IsNull(result.Model);
        }
    }
}
```

The `Index()` is underlined with red in following line

```
ViewResult result = Index() as ViewResult;
```

This is my `HomeController`:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IEmployeeRepository _employeeRepository;

    public HomeController(IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository)
    {
        _employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetAllEmployee()
    {
        var allEmployee = _employeeRepository.AllEmployee();
        var j = Json(allEmployee);
        return j;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetEmployeeDetails(int id)
    {
        var employee = _employeeRepository.Get(id);
        return Json(employee);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to do a few simple unit tests for my simple project. Any ideas? Does anyone with some experience have any ideas for a beginner?

Thanks

Comment: The `Index` method is on the `HomeController` object you've just created - thus you need `ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;`

Comment: Okay thanks. I changed it now to be this             
            ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;                   But still underlined the index()                     I've no clue why. Maybe missing something package? I dont know.   It says CS1061 error

Comment: Also: I would try to **avoid** calling the unit test class the same (`HomeController`) as the class you're trying to test. In your `// Arrange` step, you're instantiating this test class - not the actual controller you want! I'd recommend to call the test class `HomeControllerTests` or something like that ....

Comment: Do you mean that the before the TestMethod I should have to write   public class HomeControllerTests       So then how should I have to change at the             // Arrange
            HomeController controller = new HomeController();         Could you please show me the right way for coding? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have **two main problems**:

1. The test class is called the same as the class you're testing - so in your `// Arrange` step, you're really instantiated the **test class** - ***NOT*** the controller you want to test!
2. The method `Index` is on the controller, so you must use the controller's instance you created in the `// Arrange` phase to make the call.

Try this code:

```
namespace UnitTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class HomeControllerTests   // call it "...Tests"
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Index_NoInputs_ReturnsDefaultViewResult()
        {
            // Arrange
            // you will need to find a way to get the dependency your 
            // controller needs - an "IEmployeeRepository"
            // Typically, a mock is used - or a separate implementation for the tests
            IEmployeeRepository repository = .......;

            HomeController controller = new HomeController(repository);

            // Act
            ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;  // call the method *on the controller*

            // Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
            Assert.AreEqual("", result.ViewName);
            Assert.IsNull(result.Model);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing,
as per convention, your test class should have the name of the class your testing with 'Tests' added to the end. eg. `MyClassTests`

The controller you are testing takes in a `IEmployeeRepository` interface, this needs to be faked/mocked and injected into the constructor of your controller.

The return type of your `Index` method is a `IActionResult`
you can capture the results as such.
Then do assertions on that result.

Take a look at how i'd structure the test.

```
[TestClass]
public class HomeControllerTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Index_NoInputs_ReturnsDefaultViewResult()
    {

        // Arrange

        //You can create fake instances of your interfaces by newing up an implementation class 
        //or 
        //by using a mocking library such as FakeItEasy
        
        IEmployeeRepository fakeRepository = A.Fake<IEmployeeRepository>();

       
        //Inject your fake interface into the controller
        HomeController controller = new HomeController(fakeRepository);

        // Act

        // this is the expected return type of your Index method
        IActionResult result = controller.Index();

        // Assert

        //Assert that you did actually get a result
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);

        //Assert that the the result is a View
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(ViewResult));

        //There was no view specified, so i expect the ViewName Property to be null
        Assert.AreEqual(null, ((ViewResult)result).ViewName);
        
    }
}
```

Hope this helps,

Orv